# electron js crear archivo json en una ruta absoluta

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

estoy realizando una aplicacion con electron js y me interesaria crear un archivo json en el directorio c:\ o alguna otra ruta absoluta. estoy usando el modulo fs pero este solo me permite utilizar rutas relativas lo cual no me interesa porque quiero guardarlo en el directorio C:/.... habra alguna forma de convertir una ruta absoluta a relativa o de crear un archivo en una ruta absoluta???... desde ya muchas gracias...

Comment: Creo que deberías pasarte por [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), en concreto [¿ Como elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿ Podrías al menos colocar el intento que has realizado con una ruta absoluta y no funcionó ? Junto con cualquier mensaje de error que hayas obtenido. **Como texto**, por favor. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas que [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) sólo trabaja con [rutas](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths) relativas?. Si usas Windows, puedes escribir la ruta absoluta en una cadena: `absPath = 'c:\\path\\to\\file.ext';` la cual corresponde a la ruta en Windows: `c:\path\to\file.ext`. Luego la usas en `fs`. Saludos

Comment: Electron usa nodejs para funcionar o hasta donde se se compila con nodejs, por lo que aquello que indicas en teoria seria posible, el problema es los permisos, no se si estas usando windows o linux, si usas windows probablemente solo necesitas dar autorizacion. si usas linux la cosa se pone un poco mas complicada.